# Filling in an array (table) with no Horizontal (row) or Vertical (column) duplicates formulaically in Excel

Tags: excel, recursion

This may be impossible, but I am trying to create a baseball fielding lineup generator that has a few constraints provided by the league (ie. must play twice in infield, twice in outfield, no repeats at any position). I think this would be fairly simple task using any programming language, but I am designing this for my 70yo uncle and he can basically only use excel with no macros. So I can't brute force my way through the problem and I don't think I understand the mathematics behind the problem well enough to even know if there is a excel formulaic solution.

At it's essence it's a Sudoku creator and solver with no repeats in the rows or columns. I have an ok solution for the infield/outfield part via ranking the individuals by position.

Recursively calculating with F9 is ok for the solution since this is just a change in the options menu, but the last time I sent him a macro his university MS account wouldn't let him run it or change the settings.

Well, I have plenty of other info and have gotten close to solutions using huge nested IFs, but  this relatively brute force method seems to be pretty dumb and is not giving great solutions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know what version of Excel your uncle has access to?

Comment: I believe he has Office 365, but not 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your uncle has access to Excel 365 (sounds like a big if), you could use sorting to remove players already used in a given row or column, e.g. like this copied down and across from B2:

```
=LET(range,$L$2:$L$27,
choice,IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,range)+COUNTIF($A2:A2,range)=0,range),
count,COUNT(choice),
sort,SORT(choice),
INDEX(sort,RANDBETWEEN(1,count)))
```

[image]

If the players were given names instead of numbers, you could try

```
=LET(range,$L$2:$L$27,
choice,IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,range)+COUNTIF($A2:A2,range)=0,range),
count,SUM(--ISTEXT(choice)),
sort,SORT(choice),
INDEX(sort,RANDBETWEEN(1,count)))
```

Comment: Going to try it now. Will report back shortly.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I had to alter it slightly on the CountIf and Count functions with Xmatch and CountA to make it work for names instead of numbers . If you know of a better way let me know. I will post what I have once I get the #N/A error out of the way.

Comment: I've added a suggestion for the case where the players are recorded as names rather than numbers - you could certainly use Xmatch and isnumber though.

Comment: Thank you for updating! The Names Formula you added seems to work, except in the case where the list of name is the same length as the table (in your case it appears to be 9 x 9). When it gets to a name that is excluded in both the row and column axis it produces a "#NUM!" error. You can iterate with F9 until you get a solution, but I wonder if there is a way to prevent this from happening in the first place. With the conditions I will need to impose on the table this may make iterating impractical.

Comment: Yes you're right, it breaks down as the size of the grid approaches the size of the roster. Then I don't think you can get away with anything less than an iterative/recursive solution. In principle you could do it with a lambda (to avoid VBA), but your uncle is even less likely to be able to run those I'm guessing.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Maybe I can coax your formula into a loop using Lambda and Let. I haven't done it before, but anything that brings Excel closer to a coding language (that doesn't throw VBA macro warnings) can't be a bad thing to learn.

Comment: It's an interesting problem and I'm sorry it's not the solution you were looking for. There is plenty of material out there on how to generate completed sudokus, but you question is slightly more general, how to create a sudoku with 9 or more different numbers/symbols. I will think a bit more about a possible lambda.

Comment: My guess is that it will need to fill up an array (range/table) in the recursion and check to see if there are any errors and then print out the full 9x9 table as a range once it doesn't find any errors. This in theory would solve my problem as a valid solution (and only a valid solution) would always be displayed. As I said before, with my additional constraints, pressing F9 isn't necessarily feasible. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: So I got my Lambda For Loop working. I named it LoopTest and used =LoopTest(0,0)
In the Name Manager I added this function and named it LoopTest:
=LAMBDA(X,Y,
IF(Y<=12=TRUE,
 IF(X<=12=TRUE,
  LoopTest(X+1,Y),
  IF(Y=12,""TEST SUCCESS",LoopTest(0,Y+1))
)))"

Comment: Going to start a New Question.

Comment: Tom, This formula is great for making a BINGO card as well, if you remove the horizontal checks and adapt the array to the rules of BINGO.